Best way to limit visibility of contacts
I am looking for the best way to limit the visibility of the "Contacts" object for some users. We are a secondment company that constantly has a flow of new contacts, but also contacts who are interested in working for the company itself, these contacts should not be visible to the rest of the organization with the exception of the HR department (a profile or group).
However, I'm kind of at a dead end here since the object has public visibility for the organization, I can't easily change this, so I was wondering if there's an alternative way of easily limiting access to these contacts.
Hopefully, there's an easy solution to this.

Restriction Rule might work but it's not yet available on Contact: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdoxOUAR/restriction-rules-for-contact-standard-object. Your best option is to change OWD to private and go from there.

There's a lot of ways to do this.
Role-Based Sharing
Put HR above the other employees. Set OWD to private, then create two sharing rules. The first shares HR to itself, the second shares employees to itself. Because HR is higher than employees, HR sees all contacts (role-inherited sharing), and employees see only their own contacts.
Group-Based Sharing
Create two Public Groups, one for HR, and one for the employees. Set OWD to private. Next, create three sharing rules: HR sharing with HR, Employees sharing with HR, and Employees sharing with Employees. Everyone will now see exactly what they're supposed to.
Criteria-Based Sharing
Configure some fields on the Contact object to determine who the record should be shared with. Set OWD to private, then proceed to make two Criteria-Based Sharing Rules, one for HR, and one for everyone else.
Apex-Based Sharing
You can write code to share the records manually. Strongly not recommended unless you have a good use case, but is listed here for completeness.
